# Exporting data from Teradata to HDFS using TDCH

Tags: hadoop, teradata

I'm trying to export a table from Teradata into a file in my hdfs using TDCH.

I'm using the below parameters :

```
hadoop jar $TDCH_JAR com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorImportTool \
        -libjars $LIB_JARS \
        -Dmapred.job.queue.name=default \
        -Dtez.queue.name=default \
        -Dmapred.job.name=TDCH \
        -classname com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver \
        -url jdbc:teradata://$ipServer/logmech=ldap,database=$database,charset=UTF16 \
        -jobtype hdfs \
        -fileformat textfile \
  -separator ',' \
  -enclosedby '"' \
        -targettable ${targetTable} \
        -username ${userName} \
        -password ${password} \
        -sourcequery "select * from ${database}.${targetTable}" \
        -nummappers 1 \
  -sourcefieldnames "" \
  -targetpaths ${targetPaths}
```

It's working, but I need the headers in the file, and when I add the parameter:

```
-targetfieldnames "ID","JOB","DESC","DT","REG" \
```

It doesnt work, I don't even generate the file anymore.

Can anyonne help me?

Comment: There isn't only one file that's written. Why do you need headers at all? Headers should only exist in the Hive metastore, not the raw data

Comment: Hey OneCricketeer, thanks for your answer, I need the headers and I didn't want to open the file and add it manually and also, the feature exists, so why not use it?

Comment: As mentioned, that's not how Hive works, though. Parquet files, for example, don't work like CSV files with column headers. And you shouldn't import CSV data anyway, if you plan on having fast queries

Comment: I see, but I'm talking about just one file, even in this case you don't recommend to add the header/ Instead, I should change the metastore, is that your recommendation?

Comment: I haven't used this teradata import tool before, so I don't know what it does. But I doubt it writes only one file unless your initial dataset is only a few MB

Comment: yes, it's a small file with dozens of rows

Comment: The `-targetfieldnames` option is only valid for `-jobtype hive` and it does not put headers in the HDFS file, it specifies Hive column names. Even then the value supplied should be a single string like "ID,JOB,DESC,DT,REG"

Comment: If you want headers in the text file, just export it from Teradata to a file, and copy (hdfs dfs -put) the file to HDFS.

Comment: Hey @Fred, thanks for your reply, please, make this an answer and I'll accept it as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-targetfieldnames` option is only valid for `-jobtype hive`.
It does not put headers in the HDFS file, it specifies Hive column names.
(There is no option to prefix CSV with a header record.)

Also the value supplied for `-targetfieldnames` should be a single string like "ID,JOB,DESC,DT,REG" rather than a list of strings.